# Navigate to the end of the page by clicking a menu

Tags: wordpress, scroll, html

If a menu is selected I want the webpage to be scrolled down to the end of a page in wordpress.

How do I set that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we need to create our custom links through WordPress menu :

- Go to Menu and add custom link with url `#`  and with whatever text you want.
- Then click screen option to tick the CSS Class Option
- From the new element which we created in the firs step click the arrow on the right side and in the CSS Classes add `down`

Now you should have custom link in your menu with custom class same like pic below:

[image]

now we need to add our Javascript code to WordPress Footer.

open your theme child functions.php and add the following code.

```
 function scrolldown()
{
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $(".down").click(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("footer").offset().top
            }, 1500);
    });
        });

    </script>

    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'scrolldown');
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 0):

A Simple jQuery Plugin for Animating Scroll,See this page
[animatescroll](https://plugins.compzets.com/animatescroll/)